# Neato Laser Scan shows impossible data's in RVIZ

Tags: ros, rviz, laser, xv-11-laser-driver, neato

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I've got my neato robotics vacuum cleaner and I'm interested in the data of the laser scanner. I did the following tutorials to connect it to ROS and plot it in RVIZ.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/xv_11_laser_driver/Tutorials/Connecting%20the%20XV-11%20Laser%20to%20USB

http://www.ros.org/wiki/xv_11_laser_driver/Tutorials/Running%20the%20XV-11%20Node#View_the_data_in_RVIZ

The data plotted by RVIZ are shown like in a random angle and also the distance is not correct. So it looks about setting random dots around the center and update them about 3 times a second (Depending on the voltage of the motor).

Analyzing the serial data on the bus it looks for me like they still stick to the protocol of LDS V2.5 described at http://xv11hacking.wikispaces.com/LIDAR+Sensor

I use ROS Fuerte, LDS V2.6.1529

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60363/neato-laser-scan-shows-impossible-data%27s-in-rviz/) by [Marcel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3276/marcel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try using the parameter :

`rosrun xv_11_laser_driver neato_laser_publisher _firmware_version:=2`

If you don't fix the parameter to 2, the LIDAR protocole will not be understood by neato_laser_publisher.

---

Originally posted by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) with karma: 429 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3276/marcel/) on 2013-04-09**:
Thank you for this answer. This solved the problem.

**Comment by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) on 2013-04-10**:
You're welcome ! Don't hesitate to mark the correct answer ;)